# What is a ridge - Hill climbing

Tags: algorithms, optimization, terminology

I do not understand what is a ridge for hill climbing. The definition I found is a place where all points appear like a maximum, but how is that different than a plateau?

Comment: I can't speak with any authority, but from your description I can guess. On a plateau, there are no gradients. On a ridge (say, a two-dimensional line of maxima in a 3d space), each point has gradients pointing to it (from all but two (?) directions).

Answer (score 3):

The same answer you'd get on [The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/): it's one of these.

[image]
<sup>Photo: ridge from Mount OtenSho to Mount Tsubakuro, Japan. By Alpsdrake; public domain; from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridge#/media/File:Tsubakurodake_from_Otenshodake_2002-8-22.jpg)</sup>

On a plateau, your value doesn't change much if you move in *any* direction. On a ridge, your value doesn't change much if you move in one direction, but it falls a lot if you move in the other directions.